# Upper-bound on summation of form $\sum_{i=1}^{t} \frac{\alpha^{t-i}}{\sqrt{i}}$, where $\alpha <1$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, bounds-of-integration

Suppose we are given a fraction $\alpha <1$. My question is whether we can derive an upper bound on summations of the following form:

$$S_t= \sum_{i=1}^{t} \frac{\alpha^{t-i}}{\sqrt{i}},$$ where $\alpha <1$.

I have tried to tackle this by bounding the summation by an integral. But it then boils down to bounding integrals of the form $ \int_{x=0}^{t} e^{x^2} dx $, for which I am not sure if there are known bounds (other than using complimentary/imaginary error functions). Summation by parts also doesn't seem to help much. Any pointers on how we can go about bounding $S_t$ would be very helpful. My conjecture is that $S_t = O(t^{-\beta})$ for some suitable $\beta >0$ (most likely $\beta=1/2$) based on Matlab plots.

Comment: you could bound with a geometric sum, as $\alpha^{-i} / \sqrt{i} \leq \alpha^{-i}=(1/\alpha)^i$

Comment: Sure, but not using the terms in the denominator would lead to a very loose upper-bound.

Comment: So you are interested in the large $t$ limit?

Answer (score 2):

Start from the identity
$$
\frac 1{\sqrt j} = \frac 1{\sqrt \pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-j x^2}dx
$$
to obtain
$$
\sum_{j=1}^t\frac {a^{t-j}}{\sqrt j} = \frac 1{\sqrt \pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{a^t-e^{-t x^2}}{a e^{x^2}-1}dx.
$$
Change variable $y^2=tx^2$ to obtain
$$
\sum_{j=1}^t\frac {a^{t-j}}{\sqrt j} = \frac 1{\sqrt {\pi t}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{a^t-e^{-y^2}}{a e^{y^2/t}-1}dy.
$$
It should be possible then to rigorously show that since
$$
\frac{a^t-e^{-y^2}}{a e^{y^2/t}-1}\to \frac{e^{-y^2}}{1-a},\qquad t\to+\infty
$$
(because $a<1$) then
$$
\sum_{j=1}^t\frac {a^{t-j}}{\sqrt j} =\frac{ t^{-1/2}}{1-a}(1+o(1)),\qquad t\to+\infty.
$$

Comment: This is very helpful, thanks!